# AutoGPT Forge Installation Error: Can't assign requested address

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, gpt-4, autogpt

I am trying to install AutoGPT on Mac using the following tutorial: https://aiedge.medium.com/autogpt-forge-a-comprehensive-guide-to-your-first-steps-a1dfdf46e3b4

I performed the exact same steps as instructed.

However, I faced an error here:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7zI0.png)

I tried using Docker, which worked. However, I am looking for the approach without docker.